# Difficulty in android studio linearLayout in placing button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

Following is XML code I've made in order to create simple chatting app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.chatclient1.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="5pt"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="0pt">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/message_hint"
             />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"

            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:padding="5pt"
        android:background="@null">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/messageList"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:background="@null" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

The actual problem is whenever I've multi-line message, the **send** button also moves up like:

[image]

I want to fix my send button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="com.example.chatclient1.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:padding="5pt"
    android:background="@null">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/messageList"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:background="@null" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:padding="5pt"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_margin="0pt">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/message_hint"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and add this lines to `MainActivity.java` for keyboard in `onCreate()`

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Safa great job